# Debugging Heroku Procfile

Tags: heroku, procfile

I'm attempting something on Heroku that involves trying out many permutations of the procfile.

Is there a way to modify the procfile directly and restart? The only way I've found in the docs is to do a full heroku git-commit-push-build cycle. That's a very slow way to test variations on a procfile, to say nothing of the mess it makes in one's git history.